# Questions on Symplectic approach to canonical transformations

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Reading section 9.4 of *Classical Mechanics by Goldstein*, I got a question in my mind. That is, it says that for restricted canonical transformation, we have the new Hamiltonian equal to the old one. I know it's easy to be proved by generating function, but the book just claiming it without proving or providing any physical meaning? Also, the first half of this section provides the following so-called **direct conditions** by writing out the differential form of $Q(q,p)$ and $P(q,p)$ and compare them with Hamilton's equations of motion.

[image]

[image]

And I have no idea about its link to the sympletic condition

$$\mathbf{M}\mathbf{J}\mathbf{M}^{T} = \mathbf{J}\tag{9.55}$$

Can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite the symplectic condition (9.55) as
$$M^TJ~=~JM^{-1}.$$
Next use that the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is
$$ M^I{}_J~=~\left(\frac{\partial Z^I}{\partial z^J}\right)_{\!z},\qquad I,J~\in~\{1,\ldots,2n\},$$
so that the inverse matrix is
$$ (M^{-1})^I{}_J~=~\left(\frac{\partial z^I}{\partial Z^J}\right)_{\!Z},\qquad I,J~\in~\{1,\ldots,2n\}.$$
Here $z^I$ and $Z^J$ denote the old and new canonical coordinates, respectively.

Comment: Elegant! Many thanks!